# How to trigger an action once on overscroll in Kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I have a `ScrollView` that's supposed to have an update feature when you overscroll to the top (like in many apps). I've found a way to trigger it when the overscroll exceeds a certain threshold, but it triggers it a lot of times, as the `on_overscroll` event is triggered on every movement. So is there a way to limit it?
My code looks like this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

from kivy.effects.dampedscroll import DampedScrollEffect

class Effect(DampedScrollEffect):
    def on_overscroll(self, *args):
        super().on_overscroll(*args)
        if self.overscroll < -50:
            print('hey')

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sv = ScrollView(effect_cls = Effect,
                        size_hint_y = 0.2)

        gl = GridLayout(cols = 1,
                        size_hint_y = None)
        gl.bind(minimum_height = gl.setter('height'))

        for i in range(5):
            gl.add_widget(Button(text = str(i),
                                 size_hint = (None, None)))

        sv.add_widget(gl)

        return sv

TestApp().run()
```

So, as you can see, when the overscroll goes beyond 50, it prints a simple message. But when you actually try it, you'll see that it prints it many times. What I want for it is to trigger an event, stay untriggerable for some time (like a second) and update the content. I've tried messing with boolean flags and `Clock`, but it didn't work. What could be done here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a stateful decorator here:

```
class call_control:

    def __init__(self, max_call_interval):
        self._max_call_interval = max_call_interval
        self._last_call = time()

    def __call__(self, function):

        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            now = time()

            if now - self._last_call > self._max_call_interval:
                self._last_call = now

                function(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapped


class Effect(DampedScrollEffect):

    def on_overscroll(self, *args):
        super().on_overscroll(*args)

        if self.overscroll < -50:
            self.do_something()

    @call_control(max_call_interval=1)
    def do_something(self):
        print('hey')
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this an old question but someone might find it useful
This is a sample from tshirtman's github gist

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.clock import mainthread
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, BooleanProperty



KV = '''
FloatLayout:
    Label:
        opacity: 1 if app.refreshing or rv.scroll_y > 1 else 0
        size_hint_y: None
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        text: 'Refreshing…' if app.refreshing else 'Pull down to refresh'
    RecycleView:
        id: rv
        data: app.data
        viewclass: 'Row'
        do_scroll_y: True
        do_scroll_x: False
        on_scroll_y: app.check_pull_refresh(self, grid)
        RecycleGridLayout:
            id: grid
            cols: 1
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            default_size: 0, 36
            default_size_hint: 1, None
<Row@Label>:
    _id: 0
    text: ''
    canvas:
        Line:
            rectangle: self.pos + self.size
            width: 0.6
'''

class Application(App):
    data = ListProperty([])
    refreshing = BooleanProperty()

    def build(self):
        self.refresh_data()
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def check_pull_refresh(self, view, grid):
        max_pixel = 200
        to_relative = max_pixel / (grid.height - view.height)
        if view.scroll_y < 1.0 + to_relative or self.refreshing:
            return

        self.refresh_data()

    def refresh_data(self):
        Thread(target=self._refresh_data).start()

    def _refresh_data(self):
        self.refreshing = True
        sleep(2)

        self.append_data([
            {'_id': i, 'text': 'hello {}'.format(i)}
            for i in range(len(self.data), len(self.data) + 50)
        ])
        self.refreshing = False

    @mainthread
    def append_data(self, data):
        self.data = self.data + data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Application().run()
```