# How to use the ScrollView on PC?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I have tried to add a simple scroll view on PC, I define the scroll view like any other widget and then adds its layout and that I then add the widgets.

Here is the code I use:

```
        Window.size = (339, 600)
        self.w1 = self
        with self.w1.canvas.before:
            Color(0.941176, 0.941176, 0.941176, 1)
            self.rect = Rectangle(size=self.w1.size, pos=self.w1.pos)
        self.w1.bind(pos=self.update_rect, size=self.update_rect)
        self.scroll1 = ScrollView(size_hint=(None, 1), size=(Window.width, Window.height),scroll_type = ['bars',"content"])
        self.w1.add_widget(self.scroll1)
        self.scroll1_layout = RelativeLayout(pos_hint ={'x':0.0, 'y':0.0},size_hint = (0.626844, 1))
        self.scroll1.add_widget(self.scroll1_layout)
        self.button1 = Button(text = "Button", pos_hint ={'x':0.568182, 'y':0.47585}, size_hint = (1.30682, 0.0545617))
        self.scroll1_layout.add_widget(self.button1)
        self.button2 = Button(text = "Button", pos_hint ={'x':0.227273, 'y':0.864937}, size_hint = (0.909091, 0.0992844))
        self.scroll1_layout.add_widget(self.button2)
```

How do I make it so that it has a button and below the widget origin. the widget origin is the bottom left of the widget and the bottom below it would not be visible until I scrolled down.

Thank You for any help.

Comment: I think you will find your answer in this similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40320579/how-to-trigger-an-action-once-on-overscroll-in-kivy

Comment: that doesn't help, the problem is that the widgets i add do go on properly and therefore I cant scroll